# How do I safely upgrade from Django 1.0.2 to 1.3.1?

Tags: django, upgrade, production-environment, migrate

Will the following work:

1. Un-installing django 1.0.2
2. Installing django 1.3.1
3. Starting a 'new' project with the same name as the old one.
4. Manually import all of my old apps etc.
5. Cross my fingers I've not killed anything.

Presumably there are some significant differences between the versions so would that work? ..and is there a less painful (safe) way to do this?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

It is very likely that things will break--there have been a lot of (good!) changes in Django since the old 1.0 days.  Your first step really should probably be reading the release notes for each major version of Django along your upgrade path (particularly the "Backwards Incompatible Changes" sections) to get an idea of what changes have happened and what you'll need to change.

You also need to plan to do the upgrade in development (not production!) first--you'll almost certainly need to update your project in quite a few places, so you'll want to do that offline and then move the updated code into production after you've finished testing.

Release Notes:

https://docs.djangoproject.com/en/dev/releases/1.1/

https://docs.djangoproject.com/en/dev/releases/1.2/

https://docs.djangoproject.com/en/dev/releases/1.3/

Answer (score 1):

First, you should definitely do this process in a development environment first. Create a dump of your production DB if you need it, and import it into your development database.

"Un-installing" Django is unnecessary. I'd recommend simply renaming the `django` folder in your site-packages directory to something like `django_old` and then install the new version of Django.

Start up your development environment with `runserver` and see what happens. Run the testsuite to make sure your apps and third-party apps you're using don't have any major issues.

If everything works fine, you can then repeat the process on your production machine. Honestly, you really shouldn't have many problems, though. Django very rarely deprecates anything, and when they do, there's always deprecation warnings for multiple versions, before it actually ceases to function. Correct any deprecation warnings you get as soon as possible though.

Answer (score 1):

> is there a less painful (safe) way to do this?

Yes. **Always** use [virtualenv](http://www.virtualenv.org/) for **all** your [new] production rollouts, **starting with this one**. :)

Then there's no biggie in having a staging version of the new instance up and running with a different version of Django (and possibly also newer versions of other python libraries too).

You can keep your old version up and running until you're sure you're ready to perform the upgrade.

Obviously you'll need to make sure you're pointing your new version at a different database and running on a different port while testing.  Other than that it should be nice and simple.

As noted by Michael, you'll pretty much **definitely** find that you'll need to make some changes from 1.0->1.3, and you'll want to address those in a development environment first before thinking about your production upgrade.

Couple of useful pointers:

- http://www.saltycrane.com/blog/2009/05/notes-using-pip-and-virtualenv-django/
- http://www.clemesha.org/blog/modern-python-hacker-tools-virtualenv-fabric-pip